# How to use infer_vector for more than one document?

Tags: doc2vec

I have a trained doc2vec model. Now I have to create vectors for 5 documents using infer_vector. But infer_vector can create vectors for one document at a time. How do I send all 5 sentence and append the result to get (5,50) dataframe?

```
 def InferVector(prop,log,New_std_nested_list):
    Vec_df = np.array([])
    fname = (prop.get("Filepaths","Model_Saving_Path")+'model_July12_doc2vec_ELA.bin')
    model = Doc2Vec.load(fname)
    for i in range( 0, len(New_std_nested_list) ):
      temp = New_std_nested_list[i]
      vec = model.infer_vector([temp])
    Vec_df = np.append(Vec_df,vec)
    return Vec_df
```

Iteration is not woking. Is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it only infers one vector at a time, you will have to call it multiple times in a loop. But you should be able to pre-allocate the numpy array, and assign each result into its proper row. For example:

```
vec_df = np.array(5,50)
```

...then inside your loop...

```
vec_df[i] = model.infer_vector(list_of_words)
```

...with no further re-assignments to `vec_df` or indexes-of-`vec_df`.

Note that:

- `infer_vector()` requires a list-of-words, that should have been pre-processed/tokenized in the same way as the model's training texts, so that tokens match to the maximum extent. (Words not in the model will be silently ignored. So, if the model was trained with all lowercase-tokens, but then you try to `.infer_vector(['Mikey', 'REALLY', 'LIKES', 'McDonalds'])`, all those capitalized words will be missing from the model, all will be ignored, and the resulting vector will be a randomly-initialized vector that had no effective inference performed.)
- `infer_vector()` often benefits from more than the default `epochs`, especially for shorter texts